# Iterate XML tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, xml-parsing

I have a `var` with the content that is shown in the bottom. The idea is iterate over this `var` and get the content betwen `<module>` and `</module>` tags and insert it into `array var`.

```
<module>
    <title>Tag1</title>
    <multipleChoice>
        <option>option 1</option>
    </multipleChoice>
</module>
<module>
    <title>Tag2</title>
    <multipleChoice>
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
    </multipleChoice>
</module>
<module>
    <title>Tag4</title>
    <multipleChoice>
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
    </multipleChoice>
</module>
```

So this `array var` is going to save in the `[0]` position and so on:

```
 <module>
    <title>Tag1</title>
    <multipleChoice>
        <option>option 1</option>
    </multipleChoice>
</module>
```

What I have tried so far is getting each `module tag` in this way and insert into each array position. I have read about `xmlDoc Parser` but not sure if it's the best approach to do this.

```
//Get module section xml
var array = [];
var startPos = str.indexOf("<module>");
var endPos = str.indexOf("</module>");
var xmlModule = str.substring(startPos,endPos).trim();

array[0] = xmlModule;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DOMParser` to parse the string to a valid DOM element

1. Create a `root` (any name for that matter) element for making it parseable.
2. Loop through the modules and get the array as desired.

See demo below:

```js
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml = `<root>
<module>
    <title>Tag1</title>
    <multipleChoice>
        <option>option 1</option>
    </multipleChoice>
</module>
<module>
    <title>Tag2</title>
    <multipleChoice>
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
    </multipleChoice>
</module>
<module>
    <title>Tag4</title>
    <multipleChoice>
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
    </multipleChoice>
</module>
</root>`;
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");

var result = Array.prototype.map.call(
xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('module'), function(e){
  return e.outerHTML.replace(/\s/g, '');
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Simple enough! Thanks.